# dropped phone in water and it had holes in it what do i do?

Tags: battery

I dropped my lg sty lo 3 in water on accident and it had to holes in the screen  the phone turns on but it does not let me click on the screen I put it in rice but it does not work and I don"t have money to buy a new one what can I do?

Comment: Get it fixed by a professional. There is nothing substantial we can do about this from here.

Comment: You switched on too early that was a mistake. Watch this video how to remove the battery. Keep it off for about ~1 week. Dry your phone in the sun or oven (max 70 °C degree celsius/ 150 °F degree fahrenheit) https://youtu.be/xWD61VPnJEs buy USB-OTG adapter and connect a mouse, this should give you opportunity to enable usb-debugging in developer settings and backup your data

Comment: please check duplicate questions for answers too https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-damage